# Interpreting Cassandra replication json string

Tags: cassandra

When I run the following command in cqlsh

```
SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;
```

I get a list of keyspaces and for the replication column there is a json string that looks like the one below

```
 {'QQQ': '3', 'AAA': '3', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy'}
```

What are the number 3's in the string above? are they related to write level and read level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number 3 there is the number of replicas that given keyspace will have in the datacenter with given name (`QQQ` or `AAA` correspondingly). The consistency levels (CL) could use this number to calculate the number of confirmations the operation should receive to be marked successful. But this depend on specific CL - for example, `LOCAL_QUORUM` will use only `3` if it's run in the `AAA` DC, while `QUORUM` will use `6` (3 for `AAA` + 3 for `QQQ`).